# How do I debug Ruby's method_missing?

Tags: ruby, debugging, metaprogramming

Let me clarify this a bit...

I have a class that handles XML files. This class implements method_missing and used the method passed as the identifier of a tag, and then returns an object that represents the XML node for that tag. The code is more or less like this:

```
def method_missing(m, *args, &block)
  XmlNode.new(@xml.at_css(m.to_s.upcase))
end
```

I've done something weird, though, and sometimes the `m` parameter is not being sent to the method call.

Is there a way for me to pinpoint which of the calls is the culprit?

One way that I can think of is to log the method call itself, but how do I do that from within method_missing?

Comment: if you know which request causes the problem then you could use `abort object_name.to_yaml`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very crude way would be to output the call stack by putting

```
puts caller
```

right above your XmlNode... line. That will output the call stack and you can see who called the method.

Comment: Thanks. It was quite crude and didn't point me directly to the culprit, but it greatly reduced the number of suspects.

Comment: +1 but it's often a good idea to have `inspect` after the variable when printf debugging.